# How to create a index in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a sql query like this:

```
 Select ah.CODE,
          case when ( (t.narration)='' OR (t.narration) is NULL) then concat(isnull(v.nameandaddress,''),' ', (v.remarks)) else (t.narration) end as narration, 
          v.VOUCHERNO,  
          case when t.CREDITDEBIT = 1 then t.amount else 0 end as dr_amount,  
          case when t.CREDITDEBIT = 0 then t.amount else 0 end as cr_amount,  
          v.issueDate,
          ag.NAME , 
          ah.name, 
          (v.remarks) 
from voucher v   
inner join transactiondetails t on t.tx_voucher_id = v.voucherId and 
t.tx_voucher_branch = v.sourceUnit  
inner join accounthead ah on t.accounthead_id = ah.ID  
inner join accountgroup ag on ag.ID=ah.accountgroup_id  
 where v.sourceunit=279 
   and v.issueDate between '2017-04-01 00:00:00' and '2018-01-18 00:00:00' 
   and v.ISCANCELLED=0 
   and ah.code in ('1412')  
order by ah.name, v.issuedate, v.voucherid
```

If i had given a index to the table transactiondetails,will it help this query ?

**Index created is mentioned below**

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_transactiondetails_ID_Branch ON  transactiondetails 
(tx_voucher_id,tx_voucher_branch,accounthead_id) INCLUDE 
 (narration,CREDITDEBIT,amount)
```

From the above Index creation query,we have used **INCLUDE** keyword for some columns. Now i need to know, **how can i create the above mentioned index creation query in MySQL** ?

Comment: mysql does't support `INCLUDE` like in `SQL Server`. You have to include all column names instead. `CREATE INDEX IDX_transactiondetails_ID_Branch ON  transactiondetails 
(tx_voucher_id,tx_voucher_branch,accounthead_id,narration,CREDITDEBIT,amount)`

Comment: Tip: Indexes are not mentioned in the ANSI SQL standard! Every brand of SQL database implements indexes their own way, as vendor-specific extensions to SQL. So you really need to read about the syntax and features supported by the database product you use, and don't assume syntax that works in Microsoft will work in any other brand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_transactiondetails_ID_Branch ON  transactiondetails (tx_voucher_id, tx_voucher_branch, accounthead_id, narration, CREDITDEBIT, amount)
```

MySQL does not support "INCLUDE", so you have to create a multiple-column index.

Read more here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: The beautiful thing about this way of creating an index in MySQL is that it is compatible with H2 as well. Thanks! My embedded database tests work again!